# Conventions for Kazhdan Lusztig-polynomials and the form of the KL-conjecture

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, symmetric-groups, hecke-algebras

This is a follow-up question to [Reference request: Presentations of Hecke algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409740/reference-request-presentations-of-hecke-algebras).
In the common definition
$$H_t = \langle T_1,\dotsc, T_n \mid \text{braid relations, and for all i: $T_i^2 = t + (t-1)T_i$}\rangle$$
of the Hecke algebra with KL-basis $C'_w$ and KL-polynomials $n_{vw}$, the KL-conjecture states that the multiplicity of the simple module $L(w)$ in a Jordan-Hölder series for the Verma module $M(v)$ is given by
$$[M(v):L(w)]=n_{w_0v,w_0w}.$$
There is also an interpretation of the coefficients of different exponents, due to Jantzen.
However, owing to the lectures I attended, I am more used to the presentation
$$H'_q = \langle H_1,\dotsc, H_n \mid \text{braid relations, and for all i: $H_i^2 = 1 + (q^{-1}-q)H_i$}\rangle.$$
For $q=t^{-1/2}$ and $H_s=qT_s$ both are isomorphic.
Let $p_{vw}$ be the base change coefficients from the basis $H_\bullet$ to $C'_\bullet$.

**Question:** Is it true that $p_{vw}=n_{w_0w,w_0v}$?

**Attempt:** We know $C'_{w}=q^{-\ell (w)/2}\sum _{{v\leq w}}n_{vw}T_{v}$. By putting $T_v=t^{\ell(v)/2}H_v$ into the formula, we get
$$C'_{w}=\sum _{{v\leq w}}\underbrace{q^{\ell{v}/2-\ell (w)/2} n_{vw}}_{p_{vw}} H_{v}$$
I don't see how to prove the requested property for $p_{vw}$.

Comment: Usually, one sets $t=1$ (equivalently, $q=1$) in the KL conjecture (though, Jantzen has an interpretation of $t$ in terms of levels in the filtration). As you have written, $p=n$ up to a power of $q$. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the following: I wonder whether $p_{vw} = n_{w_0w,w_0v}$ and not whether $p_{vw}(1) = n_{vw}(1)$.

Comment: Why would $p_{v,w}=n_{w_0v,w_0w}$? Wouldn't you conclude from your formula that $p_{w_0v,w_0w}=n_{w_0v,w_0w}$ up to a power of $q$?

Comment: Yes that is my problem :) Computing KL-polynomials and comparing them to composition series of Vermas (with the Jantzen interpretation) suggests to me that $[M(v):L(w)]=p_{vw}$. But this does not match the usual formulae :-\

Comment: To see how to switch between these polynomials, you should see Soergels paper on KL-polynomials. He mentions how to do this.

Comment: I suppose you mean Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials and a combinatoric for tilting modules. He seems to use $H$ as I do, $C'=\underline{H}$ and $\underline{\tilde{H}}$ is $C$ in KL. However, I still only obtain conversion formulas of the above shape.

For instance, with gradings I expect $[M(e):L(e)]_q = 1$ because $L(e)$ is the head. But the common formula would give $\cdots = n_{w_0,w_0}$ which cannot be the correct value. This is why I asked whether $[M(v):L(w)]_q = n_{w_0w,w_0v} = p_{vw}$.

Comment: Yeah, I have now also managed to completely confuse myself about which bases and which polynomials do what. I has forgotten that the relevant basis here is not the one Soergel works with directly, though on the Lie algebra side the relation is fairly straightforward due to BGG reciprocity (so one set of polynomials give composition factors in Vermas, the other gives Verma factors in Projectives).

Comment: BTW, you might be interested in taking a look at the paper by Stroppel called Category $\mathcal{O}$: gradings and translation functors, since that gives a more general view of the version of Jantzen you mention here. It also discusses some of the KL combinatorics, but in a somewhat disguised way, which may not be that easy to extract information from.

Comment: "so one set of polynomials give composition factors in Vermas, the other gives Verma factors in Projectives": Shouldn't these be the same polynomials by $[P(w):M(v)]=[M(v):L(w)] \stackrel{?}{=} p_{(w_0)v,(w_0)w}$?

Comment: Right, the multiplicities are the same, but the gradings might not be (this is one of the things Stroppel details in that paper).

Comment: Ohh, and if you want to make sure I notice that you have commented, you need to put @myname there.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The first equality in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413092/conventions-for-kazhdan-lusztig-polynomials-and-the-form-of-the-kl-conjecture?noredirect=1#comment4991135_2413092) indeed is stated in Stroppel's paper (thm. 7.6). Now the solution whether there belong $w_0$'s or not is rather easy: with $w_0$ is for modules $M(w\cdot\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ *antidominant*. My implicit assumption that lead to confusion was to assume $\lambda$ to be *dominant*.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Yet another thing that tends to cause confusion because of different conventions (I usually go with dominant since I prefer the principal block and there it just feels more natural to label thing by $w.0$).